# Detect downhill segments

Tags: python, scipy

I have elevation data along a specific path. I'd like to detect downhill segments on this path.
I managed to find the location of local peaks and valleys through the  `scipy.signal` function `find_peaks`.
And then used the following code to plot the data and add the downhill segments in red:

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


elev = np.array([1601.9, 1584.7, 1583.3, 1587.4, 1608.4, 1608.2, 1608.6, 1604.1, 1607.1, 1619.1, 1616.1, 1615.6, 1619.3, 1611.4, 1602.0, 1597.1, 1587.5, 1588.6, 1571.3, 1556.2, 1516.4, 1497.2, 1497.5, 1493.5, 1490.0, 1495.4, 1507.4, 1482.1, 1481.1, 1480.2, 1472.2, 1471.8, 1453.9, 1456.2, 1446.1, 1457.5, 1447.8, 1447.0, 1447.6, 1443.3, 1440.5, 1434.4, 1433.9, 1434.5, 1435.7, 1437.4, 1436.3, 1426.9, 1451.7, 1471.0, 1474.2, 1480.8, 1482.0, 1480.8, 1475.3, 1474.9, 1474.8, 1476.7, 1476.6, 1477.4, 1475.9, 1478.2, 1491.6, 1495.2, 1496.9, 1495.1, 1495.3, 1487.5, 1487.7, 1484.6, 1483.4, 1482.7, 1481.5, 1481.9, 1481.6, 1487.7, 1494.5, 1495.0, 1494.9, 1492.9, 1487.2, 1476.4, 1475.8, 1476.4, 1476.6, 1448.0, 1478.4, 1464.6, 1492.3, 1466.2, 1435.1, 1454.3, 1455.2, 1452.3, 1451.8, 1451.7, 1451.3, 1452.1, 1454.9, 1454.6, 1454.2, 1439.9, 1464.1, 1484.4, 1490.4, 1471.3, 1480.6, 1447.9, 1474.8, 1469.3, 1470.4, 1470.0, 1469.2, 1473.6, 1473.8, 1490.0, 1490.8, 1491.2, 1490.0, 1487.6, 1486.4, 1486.6, 1491.5, 1495.2, 1496.8, 1495.0, 1495.6, 1487.4, 1487.4, 1484.6, 1483.4, 1482.0, 1482.7, 1482.4, 1481.6, 1481.9, 1481.6, 1487.4, 1494.5, 1494.7, 1495.1, 1494.1, 1492.3, 1492.9, 1487.3, 1476.3, 1476.0, 1476.6, 1476.6, 1431.7, 1479.9, 1466.1, 1492.0, 1472.1, 1465.5, 1437.7, 1448.2, 1462.7, 1463.1, 1500.5, 1493.0, 1461.8, 1483.7, 1462.0, 1451.8, 1431.0, 1418.8, 1405.5, 1403.7, 1372.9, 1380.6, 1385.0, 1388.1, 1392.9, 1413.8])
peaks,_ = find_peaks(elev)
valleys, _ = find_peaks(-elev)
plt.plot(elev)
plt.plot(peaks, elev[peaks], 'x')
plt.plot(valleys, elev[valleys], 'x')

if peaks[0] < valleys[0]:
        for i in range(len(peaks)-1):
            plt.plot(range(peaks[i], valleys[i]+1), elev[peaks[i]:valleys[i]+1], 'r')
else:
    for i in range(len(peaks)):
        plt.plot(range(peaks[i], valleys[i+1]+1), elev[peaks[i]:valleys[i+1]+1], 'r')
plt.show()
```

This works and gives the following result:[image]

However, I don't want every little peak to show up so I added the prominence parameter to 10:

```py
peaks,_ = find_peaks(elev, prominence=10)
valleys, _ = find_peaks(-elev, prominence=10)

plt.plot(elev)
plt.plot(peaks, elev[peaks], 'x')
plt.plot(valleys, elev[valleys], 'x')

if peaks[0] < valleys[0]:
    for i in range(len(peaks)-1):
        plt.plot(range(peaks[i], valleys[i]+1), elev[peaks[i]:valleys[i]+1], 'r')
else:
    for i in range(len(peaks)):
        plt.plot(range(peaks[i], valleys[i+1]+1), elev[peaks[i]:valleys[i+1]+1], 'r')
plt.show()
```

Which gives: [image]
This also works fine until around index 135 because there are two valleys without a valley in between.
Is there a way to solve this?

TL;DR: I'm looking for a way to indicate valleys and peaks with a given prominence in a signal where the valleys and peaks alternate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I've taken is to go through the list of peaks, and for each peak determine the next valley. This allows us to pair each peak with the next closest valley to it:

[image: result]

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

elev = np.array([1601.9, 1584.7, 1583.3, 1587.4, 1608.4, 1608.2, 1608.6, 1604.1, 1607.1, 1619.1, 1616.1, 1615.6, 1619.3, 1611.4, 1602.0, 1597.1, 1587.5, 1588.6, 1571.3, 1556.2, 1516.4, 1497.2, 1497.5, 1493.5, 1490.0, 1495.4, 1507.4, 1482.1, 1481.1, 1480.2, 1472.2, 1471.8, 1453.9, 1456.2, 1446.1, 1457.5, 1447.8, 1447.0, 1447.6, 1443.3, 1440.5, 1434.4, 1433.9, 1434.5, 1435.7, 1437.4, 1436.3, 1426.9, 1451.7, 1471.0, 1474.2, 1480.8, 1482.0, 1480.8, 1475.3, 1474.9, 1474.8, 1476.7, 1476.6, 1477.4, 1475.9, 1478.2, 1491.6, 1495.2, 1496.9, 1495.1, 1495.3, 1487.5, 1487.7, 1484.6, 1483.4, 1482.7, 1481.5, 1481.9, 1481.6, 1487.7, 1494.5, 1495.0, 1494.9, 1492.9, 1487.2, 1476.4, 1475.8, 1476.4, 1476.6, 1448.0, 1478.4, 1464.6, 1492.3, 1466.2, 1435.1, 1454.3, 1455.2, 1452.3, 1451.8, 1451.7, 1451.3, 1452.1, 1454.9, 1454.6, 1454.2, 1439.9, 1464.1, 1484.4, 1490.4, 1471.3, 1480.6, 1447.9, 1474.8, 1469.3, 1470.4, 1470.0, 1469.2, 1473.6, 1473.8, 1490.0, 1490.8, 1491.2, 1490.0, 1487.6, 1486.4, 1486.6, 1491.5, 1495.2, 1496.8, 1495.0, 1495.6, 1487.4, 1487.4, 1484.6, 1483.4, 1482.0, 1482.7, 1482.4, 1481.6, 1481.9, 1481.6, 1487.4, 1494.5, 1494.7, 1495.1, 1494.1, 1492.3, 1492.9, 1487.3, 1476.3, 1476.0, 1476.6, 1476.6, 1431.7, 1479.9, 1466.1, 1492.0, 1472.1, 1465.5, 1437.7, 1448.2, 1462.7, 1463.1, 1500.5, 1493.0, 1461.8, 1483.7, 1462.0, 1451.8, 1431.0, 1418.8, 1405.5, 1403.7, 1372.9, 1380.6, 1385.0, 1388.1, 1392.9, 1413.8])

peaks,_ = find_peaks(elev, prominence=10)
valleys, _ = find_peaks(-elev, prominence=10)

plt.plot(elev)
plt.plot(peaks, elev[peaks], 'x')
plt.plot(valleys, elev[valleys], 'x')

#Pair each peak with its next closest valley
peak_valley_pairs = []
for peak in peaks:
    next_valley = valleys[ np.argmax(valleys > peak) ]
    peak_valley_pairs.append( (peak, int(next_valley) ) )

#Each (peak, valley) pair defines a segment along x
#  Draw a red line for that segment    
for peak, valley in peak_valley_pairs:
    plt.plot(range(peak, valley + 1), elev[peak:valley + 1], 'r')

plt.show()
```